# Incrementing numbers in Python with beats and measures format

Tags: python, auto-increment, post-increment

I‘m totally new to program python. I‘m writing a program with two numbers in output. One number simply counting to 4. The other number progressing every time the first number returns to 1.
Here's what I have written so far:

```
import time
while True:
    beat = [1,2,3,4]
    measure = 1
    while beat ==[1]:
        measure = measure + 1
    for i in beat:
        for j in measure:
            time.sleep(1)
            print(j,i)
```

All this does is produce 1 1, 1 2, 1 3, 1 4, 1 1, 1 2, 1 3, 1 4, etc...

Thank you for (hopefully) putting up with my ignorance/problem.

Comment: Can you give an example what your desired output should look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you want console output like this (with a new line every second):

```
1 1
1 2
1 3
1 4
2 1
2 2
...
```

Then this should work:

```
import time

beat = [1,2,3,4]
measure = 1
while True:
    for i in beat:
        time.sleep(1)
        print(measure, i)
    measure = measure + 1
```

Comment: This is exactly right.  Before I read this, I had come up with a work around that was somewhat clumsy and not as ‘clean’ as this.  So thank you.  Totally new to code altogether so I really appreciate you taking the time to respond. 

Now I wil have to learn how to:   
Be able to adjust the tempo with an external potentiometer, record incoming midi data and play back outgoing midi data.  Should take me a few years to accomplish but I love learning!    

Thanks again!

Comment: @Chris: Glad I could help :) I thought it looked like a metronome. Have fun learning and realizing your project!